# JQuery and PHP - change background image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am trying to get a background image to change on the click of a link. In the page, there is a php function that gets all of the files (just images) from a directory and writes the following for each item:

```
print("
    $(\"#photo" . "$curimage\").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(\"#galleryPhoto\").css(\"background-image\", \"url(images/ints/$file)\");
        });
");
```

The entire code (for just one item) ends up looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){   

            $("#photo1").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); 
                $("#galleryPhoto").css("background-image", "url(images/ints/001.jpg)");
            });

        return false;    
        }); 
</script>
```

In the body of the page, there is another php section that does the same thing, but this time it provides the link:

```
print("<a id=\"photo" . "$curimage\" href=\"#\" >Change</a>");
```

This, of course, gives a completed link of:

```
<a id="photo1" href="#" >Change</a>
```

In addition, there is a div with the id of galleryPhoto, with the following settings in the css:

```
<div id='galleryPhoto'>
        Main photo here
</div>

#galleryPhoto {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(../images/ints/blank.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

But when the link is clicked, the background image does not change. I am clueless on what I am doing wrong. I have tried so many different things that the code is probably all messed up now, but I don't know why (JQuery newbie, sorry).

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: _"But when the link is clicked, the background image does not change."_ At `css` path to image is `../images/ints/blank.jpg` , at click event path to image  is `images/ints/001.jpg` ? Two different folders named "images" at server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `html` is being generated dynamically through `PHP` ensure that you are using the `.on` function. So anytime that your `html` is being generated dynamically it's best to use the `.on` function.

So instead of using this:

```
 $("#photo1").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $("#galleryPhoto").css("background-image", "url(images/ints/001.jpg)");
 });
```

You would use this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#photo1', function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $("#galleryPhoto").css("background-image", "url(images/ints/001.jpg)");
 });
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I don't know why, but it did. I would have never thought to do that. Thank you!

Comment: I was in the same situation a while back, don't worry! I would suggest using the `.on('click'` instead of the `.click(` from now on as you might have the same problem and forget that your `html` is being dynamically generated. With the `.on(''` you can use it for all jquery methods (change, mouseover, etc...) - http://api.jquery.com/on/ @Apolymoxic

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the height and width of your `#galleryPhoto` div because Background image base its height and width on it's container. Unlike `<img>` takes the image height and width if not defined

Comment: I did that. Sorry... I should have clarified. I have added those settings to show how I defined the #galleryPhoto